# How to add an image ( NOT background-image ) in check box and radio button styling (SVG css fill issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Css background image work just fine, I know. **But,**
I want to use an svg, and change the color dynamically. Those colors are based on themes and it is **dynamic**.

I tried adding the svg as background-image in css, But css **fill** will NOT work with background-image.

But if we add "image" instared of the background-image, fill will work.

But I don't know how to execute that,. I want to do this using CSS or JS, and not HTML.

Comment: in this case you need to put the svg inside the `<label>` for the checkbox and hide the checkbox.

Comment: @enxaneta can add with CSS or Javascript?  What I want is change SVG color using css, the color is dynamic,.